# Newton problem with object

Tags: calculus, integration

> ***i)*** Explain why: $T'(t)+kT(t)=3kt$

So, here is what I did:

Let the room temperature be $A(t)$ and $dA/dt=3$

If we use the formula for Newton's law of cooling/heating: $$T'(t)=k(A(t)-T(t))$$

$$T'(t)=3kt-kT(t)$$

$$T'(t)+kT(t)=3kt$$
I let $A(t)= 3t$ and $A'(t)=3$

> ***ii)*** If $T(0)=0$, find $T(t)$ expressed in terms of $k$

Comment: Why is your formula derivation wrong? The room temp increases by 3 degrees per hour, which means A(t) = 3t. Sub that in, and you are good.

Comment: oh god.. of course it is!

Answer (score 2):

$A(t)=3t$ is correct. Consequently $A'(t)=3$ as given in the question.

For the second part you should multiply by an integrating factor.
\begin{align*}
T'(t) + kT(t) &= 3kt\\
T'(t)e^{kt} + T(t)ke^{kt}&=3kte^{kt}\\
(T(t)e^{kt})'&=3kte^{kt}\\
T(t)e^{kt}&=\int 3kte^{kt}dt\\
T(t)e^{kt}&= 3te^{kt}- \int 3e^{kt}dt\\
T(t)e^{kt}&= 3te^{kt}- \frac{3}{k}e^{kt} + C\\
T(t)&=3t- \frac{3}{k} + Ce^{-kt}
\end{align*}

You can figure out the value of $C$ by plugging in the known values of $T(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your derivation is correct. Try to think about why $A(t) = 3t$. However, when you solved the equation, it looks like you tried to solve it as a separable DE. It is not separable, and needs to be solved as a first order linear differential equation.

$$T'(x) + kT(x) = 3kt$$
$$e^{kt}T'(x) + ke^{kt}T(x) = 3kte^{kt}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left (T(x)e^{kt}  \right ) = 3kte^{kt}$$
$$T(x)e^{kt} = 3te^{kt} - \frac{3}{k}e^{kt} + C$$
$$T(x) = 3t - \frac{3}{k} + Ce^{-kt}$$

Answer (score 1):

i) looks fine to me, although I have not checked Newton's cooling law.
$A'(t)$ would be just $3 K/h$.

ii) here you are expected to integrate the ODE.

$$
3kt = T′(t)+kT(t) = e^{-kt} \frac{d}{dt}\left( T(t) e^{kt} \right) \Rightarrow \\
\int\limits_0^t 3k\tau e^{k\tau} d\tau
= \left[ T(\tau) e^{k\tau}\right]_0^t = T(t) e^{kt} \Rightarrow \\
$$
Solving for $T$ we get:
\begin{align}
T(t) 
&= 3k \, e^{-kt} \int\limits_0^t \tau e^{k\tau} d\tau \\
&= 3k \, e^{-kt} \left( \left[ \frac{1}{k} e^{k\tau} \tau\right]_0^t - 
\frac{1}{k}\int\limits_0^t  e^{k\tau} d\tau \right) \\
&= 3k \, e^{-kt} \left( \frac{1}{k} e^{kt} t - 
\frac{1}{k} \left[ \frac{1}{k} e^{k\tau} \right]_0^t 
\right) \\
&= 3k \, e^{-kt} \left( \frac{1}{k} e^{kt} t - 
\frac{1}{k^2}e^{kt} + \frac{1}{k^2}\right) \\
&= 3t - \frac{3}{k} + \frac{3}{k} e^{-kt} \\
&= 3\left(t - \frac{1}{k} \left(1-e^{-kt} \right) \right)
\end{align}